# What #id.class css means?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I saw in a CSS declaration this:

```css
#nav.js {
    display:none;
}
```

Can someone explain what this means? The html code is the following

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does your title not answer your question? This almost looks rhetorical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `#nav.js`

This selects an element whose `id` is set to `"nav"` and has a `class` containing `"js"`.

For example, it would select any of the following elements:

```
<figure id="nav" class="js"></figure>
<figure id="nav" class="foo js"></figure>
<figure id="nav" class="js bar"></figure>
<figure id="nav" class="foo js bar"></figure>
```

But it wouldn't select any of these elements:

```
<figure></figure>
<figure id="nav"></figure>
<figure class="js"></figure>
<figure id="nav" class="foo bar"></figure>
```

#### `display: none`

This as I'm sure you're already aware sets the element to not display at all on the page.

#### `#nav.js { display: none; }`

This combines the above. It selects any element with an `id` of `"nav"` and a `class` containing `"js"` and sets it to not display on the page.

Answer (score 1):

In english, this means:

> Find me any element, with an id of `nav` **and** has a class of `js`.

In vebose CSS, `#nav.js` actually would translate to:

```
*[id='nav'][class~='js']
```

Answer (score 0):

it´s simple... When add a class `.js` the element will not display

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav" class="js">
    <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `#nav` used for to assign css for the ID element

When you use `.js` then it will assign css to all the js class elements.

When you use `#nav.js` then it will only assign to the element which have both `id=#nav` and `class='js'`

And when you declare `#nav .js` then it will assign the css to all classes which are inside the `#nav` element.